# BeanUtils - 'describe' method returning Incorrect array value

Tags: java, apache-commons-beanutils

I want to convert a bean class to a map (key=the name of the member,value=the value of the member).

I'm using the method BeanUtils.describe(beanClass);

(**Edit**:I'm using commons-beanutils 1.8.3, jdk 1.6.0_20, on commons-beanutils 1.5 it works)

The problem is that the return value is incorrect, (the map contain only the first item from the array),

the code:

```
public class Demo {

        private ArrayList<String> myList = new ArrayList<String>();

        public Demo() {
            myList.add("first_value");
            myList.add("second_value");
        }

        public ArrayList<String> getMyList() {
            return myList;
        }

        public void setMyList(ArrayList<String> myList) {
            this.myList = myList;
        }

        public static void main(String[] args) {
            Demo myBean = new Demo();
            try {
                Map describe = BeanUtils.describe(myBean);
                Iterator it = describe.entrySet().iterator();
                while (it.hasNext()) {
                    Map.Entry pairs = (Map.Entry) it.next();
                    System.out.println(String.format("key=%s,value=%s", (String) pairs.getKey(), (String) pairs.getValue()));

                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
```

- The expected output:

key=myList,value=**[first_value,second_value]**

key=class,value=class $Demo

- But the real output is:

key=myList,value=**[first_value]**

key=class,value=class $Demo

As you can see the array contains two values but the output(and the map) contains only one,why??

Thanks,

Benny

Answer (score 0):

I run you code sample on my computer, and the output is:
  key=myList,value=[first_value, second_value]
  key=class,value=class com.gpdi.infores.dao.test.Demo
Use JDK5 or higher will be OK.

Comment: Thanks for your response,
I tried to run the code with commons-beanutils 1.5, and it works. Probably there is a bug in 1.8.3.